# Create a binary column indicating the first success

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, binary-data, mutate

| Fish_ID | Instance | Success | First_Success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 |

I have a data frame with column  "Fish_ID","Instance" and"Success" and I want to create a column "First_Success", containing a 1 only at first success and otherwise 0 for each fish_ID group. In the actual data I have more than one Fish_ID. Here is an example.
I came up with this code:

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(fish_ID) %>%
  mutate(Fist_Success = ifelse(Success == 1, 1, 0))
```

But with this code, it counts for all success values that equals to 1 and I just want to it only takes for the first success as 1 for the "First_Success" column and the rest is 0 within the same fish_ID group. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(First_Success = +(Success & cumsum(Success) == 1),
         .by = Fish_ID)

#   Fish_ID Instance Success First_Success
# 1       1        0       0             0
# 2       1        1       0             0
# 3       1        2       1             1
# 4       1        3       0             0
# 5       1        4       1             0
# 6       1        5       0             0
```

It has a variant suggested by @langtang:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(First_Success = (cumsum(Success) == 1) * Success,
         .by = Fish_ID)
```

---

##### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text =
"Fish_ID    Instance    Success
1   0   0
1   1   0
1   2   1
1   3   0
1   4   1
1   5   0", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: i like this better than mine.   Also, you can just multiply the cumsum directly like `Success*(cumsum(Success)==1)`

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a number of ways to do this.. In this example below, I subtract 1 from the value of Instance in the row where Success is first equal to 1

```
df %>%
  group_by(fish_ID) %>%
  mutate(First_Success = +(Instance == min(which(Success==1))-1))
```

Another approach is to use `which.max()`, like this:

```
group_by(df, fish_ID) %>%
  mutate(First_Success = +(row_number()== which.max(Success)))
```

Output:

```
  fish_ID Instance Success First_Success
    <int>    <int>   <int>         <int>
1       1        0       0             0
2       1        1       0             0
3       1        2       1             1
4       1        3       0             0
5       1        4       1             0
6       1        5       0             0
```